# Understanding MYSQL JOINS

Tags: mysql, database, join, relational-database

I am very frustrated in Understanding the MYSQL JOINS

I tries alot but I m not getting to understand how the Joins work  I even studied about joins at [W3SCHOOLS](http://www.w3schools.com) website.and I know the difference b/w inner join,full join,left join and right join.I noted the syntax from there and thought that I know now the joins.
But problem arieses when i need to implement them in practical that time i do not get to know how to implement.I Need to understand it in more detail is only point I come up.

So please if any one can help me in understanding the mySQL Joins. please please help me.  I want to see my self as a perfect programmer very soon.

Accept my thanks in advance....

Comment: Get yourself a database and experiment. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) will be your friend.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great visual explaination: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm

**SQL Joins**

SQL Joins are used to relate information in different tables. A Join condition is a part of the sql query that retrieves rows from two or more tables. A SQL Join condition is used in the SQL WHERE Clause of select, update, delete statements.

The Syntax for joining two tables is:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3...
FROM table_name1, table_name2
WHERE table_name1.col2 = table_name2.col1;
```